# Passing more than one params to router-link in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, parameters, routes, routerlink

So I want to pass more than one params from **Home.vue** to **Movie.vue** using **params** with **router-link** like this :

```js
    <ul>
      <li class="movie-card" v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id">


    <router-link
        :to="{
          name: 'Movie',
          params: { id: movie.id, subtitle: movie.subtitle, movie: movie},
        }"
        class="movie-link"
        target="_blank"
      >

     </li>
    </ul>
```

And accepting props in **Movie.vue** like this :

```js
  props: ["id", "subtitle", "movie"],
```

And trying to acces them in **Movie.vue** like this :

```js
    <p>The movie id is {{ id }}</p>
            
    <p>detail subtitle is : {{ subtitle }}</p>
```

Notice that the **subtitle** and the Object **movie** are not passed,

Notice that I want to pass the **id**, the **subtilte**, and the Object **movie** (that is a result of API call fetch)

when I try to do a to see what are the params that are passing it confirms that only id does:

```js
    {{ this.$route.params }}

    params : { "id": "PETITOU0152W0143012" }
```

It will be all good if me if I just can pass the Object **movie** and do all what I want with it.

Comment: This isn't what params are for or how they work. Parameters add queries to the URL for fetching data. You should use only the id parameter on the movie page to fetch the correct data based on the id in the url.